# rounding values in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a small "converting" script from decimal, to fractional inches. So a 1.535 feet is converted in a string of 1' - 6 7/16".
I have all the feet and inches solved, but I run into an issue when I'm rounding off the decimal part of the inches.

Part of my code is:

```
F = 0.336 # This is the value that I get for decimal part of inches: if it is 0, the w = '0"' if it 0.999 is w = '31/32"' 
w = '0"'
if F == 0:
    w = '0"'
elif  0 < F <= 0.03125: #1/32"
    w = '1/32"'
elif 0.03125 < F <= 0.0625: #2/32"
    w = '2/32"'
elif 0.0625 < F <= 0.09375: #3/32"
    w = '3/32"'
elif 0.09375 <  F <= 0.125: #4/32"
    w = '4/32"'
elif 0.125 < F <= 0.15625: #5/32"
    w = '5/32"'

# .etc until 32/32"

print(w)
```

The issue is that my `print(w)` will result always in `0` regardless the value of F

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include all your code. You're looking for help finding a bug, but hiding the code that should deal with the 0.336 value.

Comment: You're missing a single quote after `w = '5/32"`.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it manually, in contrast to using the `fractions` module?

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier to maintain as a `while` loop where you an aggregate number that starts at 0 and increase the value to check by `0.03125` and keep checking if you're number is less than or equal to it.

Comment: @Austin - I cannot post the entire code. It's complaining that is too long. Any suggestions, how I can post it? thanks!

Comment: Maybe create a gist on github and then edit the question to add the link? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: OK thanks -  I posted it here:
 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04948084cb8a976a4d5838b606920b29

Comment: Sorry for the trouble for everybody, but seems like I should have an issue in formatting somewhere. I deleted couple comments I had in the original code (that were not posted here), and once tried on repl.it it ran ok.  Thanks for all the suggestions! Next I'll try the more sophisticated solutions (using Fractions), you guys suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may have something wrong in if else ladder check condition. if none of the condition is satisfied value of w is not modified in any if else ladder. Therefore the initialized value of w is only printed with print(w).

Comment: You can test this theory by setting the initial value of w to something like 2"

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot post the entire script. Is complaining about "too long ..." How do I go around that, and post the entire script? Thanks.

Comment: What they are suggesting is to set `w = '2"'` at the top of your fraction code. Then, if the result is 2", you know that none of your `if ... elif ... else` code was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Without your full code, we can't debug your problem, especially since the path of execution that is being taking appears to be in the portion of your code that you did not include.

This aside, it seems like you should be able to get the results you want from the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) module in the python standard library (as mentioned by @Vallentin).

Your code could be simplified to:

```
from fractions import Fraction
F = 0.336
as_fraction = Fraction(F).limit_denominator(32)
print(as_fraction.numerator, "/", as_fraction.denominator)
```

And if you want to [play around with it](https://repl.it/GIRe/1)

Comment: Apologize for not posting the entire code.

I'm trying to post it but is giving me an error that "too long by ..."
Below is how much I could post.
w = '0"'
if  0 <= F < 0.03125: #0"
 w = ' '
elif 0.03125 <= F < 0.0625: #1/32"
 w = '1/32"'
elif 0.0625 <= F < 0.09375: #2/32"
 w = '2/32"'
elif 0.09375 <=  F < 0.125: #3/32"
 w = '3/32"'
elif 0.125 <= F < 0.15625: #4/32"
 w = '4/32"'
elif 0.15625 <= F < 0.1875: #5/32"
 w = '5/32"'
#### 
elif 0.96875 <= F < 0.9999: #31/32"
 w = '31/32"'

Comment: Thanks for suggesting fractions, but unfortunately this is giving me for  F = 0.271 a 3 / 11 fraction. As this script is for construction industry, they use 1/32" or 1/16" or 1/8", etc. values. So all fractions should be a multiple of one of these. That is I went "manually" setting the tolerances. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @alc, I posted another answer that should meet your constraints, but I'd like to leave this answer in case anyone else just wants fractions and does not care what the denominator is.

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal in python, not a simple `x/y`

```
    import decimal
    alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
    blist = [32,32,32,32,32]

    for x, y in zip(alist, blist):
        print '{0}/{1} = {2},{3}'.format(x,  y, x/y, decimal.Decimal(x)/decimal.Decimal(y) )
```

The Result is:

```
1/32 = 0, using decimal 0.03125
2/32 = 0, using decimal 0.0625
3/32 = 0, using decimal 0.09375
4/32 = 0, using decimal 0.125
5/32 = 0, using decimal 0.15625
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you need a specific denominator, it seems you'll have to write the conversion logic yourself, so you can choose how you handle rounding. It seems like you have a small bug that you can't identify, which often occurs with large sections of repetitive code. You can reduce your potential for bugs by executing your conversion with a loop. Here is an example function that should achieve your desired conversion behavior:

```
def to_fraction(decimal, denominator):
  """ Converts a decimal value to a fraction with a given denominator

  If between exact fractions we round up """

  multiplier = 1 / denominator
  numerator = 0

  while decimal > numerator*multiplier:
    numerator += 1

  return str(numerator) + "/" + str(denominator)

F = 0.336
print(to_fraction(F, 32))
```

You can play around with it on repl.it: [convert to_fraction](https://repl.it/GJYS/0)